# Groovy - Converting a date string to a formatted date

Tags: date, groovy

OK, I am trying to convert a date string from a format like:

```
2014-01-21 00:00:00
```

to

```
01/21/2014
```

I have tried many variations and am crashing and burning. The issue is that to test I have to create the script, export it in a process in Bonita (a BPM software), Import it and then create some cases. This all takes a long time.

Hopefully someone knows how to do this.

Also, is there a simple groovy editor out there? That would help me learn how to write groovy very quickly.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? I'd recommend using Joda Time personally - I know there are custom Groovy libraries for date and time, but Joda Time's sole focus is on doing this sort of thing well.

Answer (score 12):

Groovy Dates have methods `parse` and `format` for converting to and from strings in various formats:

```
def format1 = '2014-01-21 00:00:00'
def format2 = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", format1).format("dd/MM/yyyy")
assert format2 == '01/21/2014'
```

The format of the format strings are the same as Java's [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: The above assertion will fail. You may want to have assert format2 == '21/01/2014'

Comment: As of (at least) Groovy 2.5.9, `Date.parse()` is deprecated, my compiler can't even locate a version of it that supports `(String, String)` and `format(String)` doesn't exist at all. This answer is not going to help anyone at this point.
The closest option is something like `LocalDate.parse(CharSequence text, DateTimeFormatter formatter)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
String olddate='2014/01/21 00:00:00'
Date date = Date.parse("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss",olddate)
String newDate = date.format( 'MM/dd/yyyy' )
log.info newDate
```